# Django: custom 404 handler that returns 404 status code

Tags: django, http-status-code-404

The project I'm working on has some data that needs to get passed to every view, so we have a wrapper around `render_to_response` called `master_rtr`.  Ok.

Now, I need our 404 pages to run through this as well.  Per [the instructions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views), I created a custom 404 handler (cleverly called `custom_404`) that calls master_rtr.  Everything looks good, but our tests are failing, because we're receiving back a 200 OK.

So, I'm trying to figure out how to return a 404 status code, instead.  There [seems to be](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/?from=olddocs#httpresponse-subclasses) an HttpResponseNotFound class that's kinda what I want, but I'm not quite sure how to construct all of that nonsense instead of using `render_to_response`.  Or rather, I could probably figure it out, but it seems like their must be an easier way; is there?

The appropriate parts of the code:

```
 def master_rtr(request, template, data = {}):
  if request.user.is_authenticated():
   # Since we're only grabbing the enrollments to get at the courses, 
   # doing select_related() will save us from having to hit database for
   # every course the user is enrolled in
   data['courses'] = \
    [e.course for e in \
     Enrollment.objects.select_related().filter(user=request.user) \
     if e.view]
  else:
   if "anonCourses" in request.session:
    data['courses'] = request.session['anonCourses']
   else:
    data['courses'] = []

  data['THEME'] = settings.THEME

  return render_to_response(template, data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

 def custom_404(request):
  response = master_rtr(request, '404.html')
  response.status_code = 404
  return response
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easy way:

```
def custom_404(request):
    response = master_rtr(...)
    response.status_code = 404
    return response
```

But I have to ask: why aren't you just using a context processor along with a RequestContext to pass the data to the views?

Comment: Ah yes, that's what I was looking for.  Updated the question with code.

Comment: Well it definitely looks like you could just be doing that in a context processor (and then adding it to the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS setting).

If you're worried about losing the simpler shortcut which uses RequestContext, you can just use django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template

Answer (score 1):

Just set [`status_code` on the response](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse.status_code).

Answer (score 1):

Into your application's views.py add:

```
# Imports
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Context, loader


##
# Handle 404 Errors
# @param request WSGIRequest list with all HTTP Request
def error404(request):

    # 1. Load models for this view
    #from idgsupply.models import My404Method

    # 2. Generate Content for this view
    template = loader.get_template('404.htm')
    context = Context({
        'message': 'All: %s' % request,
        })

    # 3. Return Template for this view + Data
    return HttpResponse(content=template.render(context), content_type='text/html; charset=utf-8', status=404)
```

The secret is in the last line: status=404

Hope it helped!